# Windows batch file to log in to remote server and kill processes?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am a QA Engineer running automated UI tests overnight, distributed over several VM's. However, sometimes a job might hang and it causes a major headache. Can I write a batch file to log into the remote server (headless would be best, since the job itself will run on a master VM) and kill the process that I need to, and then log back out? I have NO experience writing Windows batch scripts. Also - I'm using a service account, so no need to hide the password.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will kill any process whose executable is "notepad.exe" on the remote machine REMOTE_HOST (so long as you are an admin on the machine)

```
taskkill.exe /S REMOTE_HOST /FI "ImageName EQ notepad.exe"
```

See `taskkill.exe /?` for more info.

Comment: As far as credentials, you could easily make a scheduled task that logs on as anyone you want (except non-domain, non-local users), and the password would be stored in whatever semi-secure method MS employs. It's at least not stored cleartext.

Answer (score 0):

it's better you Use powershell script to `Invoked-command` because has switch named Credential on machine for authentication 
see example

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName dc -Credential dc\jack
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock {stop-process -name notepad}
```

Comment: WinRM will need to be configured on the machine for New-Session to work.

Comment: Ofcurse need it , configuration need 3 minute very simple but powershell invoked-command very usefull and powerful isn't?

Comment: I mention it because it's not configured by default. You just needed to mention the dependencies with the answer.

Comment: i recommend powershell invoke-command because has credential Just for  add Credential I know he want batch file not powershell script but can not add Credential in batch file for this issue